# Call of stopForeground and stopSelf doesn't work after closing the Application

Tags: android, android-service

I've a problem stopping my Musicservice.

The procedure:

1. I start my Activity.
2. I start my MusicService.
3. I close my App completely, the Service is Unbound from MainActivity.
4. My BroadcastReceiver registers a Button-Press from my Notification-Button, so I call stopForeground but this call doesn't get executed!

Does anybody know why?

My MusicService-Class:

```
public class MusicService extends Service
        implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
            AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        iSongPosition = 0;
        playMode = PlayMode.PASS;

        bPreparing = false;
        bNotReceiverRegistered = false;

        mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        int iAudioReqResult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

        if (iAudioReqResult != AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Sorry.")
                    .setMessage("Musixs wasn't able to gain the AudioStream garanted!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();
        }

        serviceInterface = new ServiceInterface() { ... };

        nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationBroadcast = new NotificationBroadcast();

        PlayActivity.setServiceInterface(serviceInterface);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(NotificationBroadcast.NOTIFY_PLAYPAUSE);
        intentFilter.addAction(NotificationBroadcast.NOTIFY_PREVIOUS);
        intentFilter.addAction(NotificationBroadcast.NOTIFY_NEXT);
        intentFilter.addAction(NotificationBroadcast.NOTIFY_CANCEL);

        if (!bNotReceiverRegistered) {
            registerReceiver(notificationBroadcast, intentFilter);

            bNotReceiverRegistered = true;
        }

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return musicBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
       return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        mp.reset();

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();

        notification = Build_Notification();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putLong(Constants.Preferences.lastPlayedSong, getActualSong().getID());
        editor.apply();

        startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, notification);

        bPreparing = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }

            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();

            mediaPlayer = null;
        }

        if (bNotReceiverRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(notificationBroadcast);
        }
    }

    //region Methods

    public void playSong(int index) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();

        iSongPosition = index;

        Song playSong = sSongs[iSongPosition];

        long playSongID = playSong.getID();

        Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, playSongID);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        bPreparing = true;
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        if (mediaplayerEvent != null) {
            mediaplayerEvent.onNewSong(getActualSong());
        }
    }

    public void playNext() {
        iSongPosition++;

        if (iSongPosition == sSongs.length) {
            iSongPosition = 0;
        }

        playSong(iSongPosition);
    }

    public void playPrev() {
        iSongPosition--;

        if (iSongPosition < 0) {
            iSongPosition = sSongs.length - 1;
        }

        playSong(iSongPosition);
    }

    public Song getActualSong() {
        return (sSongs != null && sSongs.length > 0) ? sSongs[iSongPosition] : null;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (mediaplayerEvent != null) {
            mediaplayerEvent.onPlayPauseToggle(true);
        }

        mediaPlayer.start();

        notification = Build_Notification();

        startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (mediaplayerEvent != null) {
            mediaplayerEvent.onPlayPauseToggle(false);
        }

        mediaPlayer.pause();

        notification = Build_Notification();

        nManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
    }

    public void playPause() {
        if (isPlaying()) {
            pause();
        }
        else {
            if (isActive()) {
                start();

            }
            else {
                playSong(iSongPosition);

                if (mediaplayerEvent != null) {
                    mediaplayerEvent.onPlayPauseToggle(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
System.out.println("Trying to stop"); //this got print out
        stopForeground(true);
System.out.println("Stopped service"); //this not
    }

    private Notification Build_Notification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;

        Intent notIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent notOpenOnClick = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        RemoteViews smallContentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_small);
        RemoteViews bigContentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_expanded);

        nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.not_playing)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle(getActualSong().getTitle())
                .setContentIntent(notOpenOnClick);

        Notification not = nBuilder.build();

        setListeners(smallContentView);
        setListeners(bigContentView);

        not.contentView = smallContentView;
        not.bigContentView = bigContentView;

        if (isPlaying()) {
            not.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.not_btnPlayPause, R.drawable.ic_pause_48dp);
            not.bigContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.not_btnPlayPause, R.drawable.ic_pause_48dp);
        }
        else {
            not.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.not_btnPlayPause, R.drawable.ic_play_48dp);
            not.bigContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.not_btnPlayPause, R.drawable.ic_play_48dp);
        }

        not.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.not_txvTitle, getActualSong().getTitle());
        not.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.not_txvAlbum, getActualSong().getAlbum());

        not.bigContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.not_txvTitle, getActualSong().getTitle());
        not.bigContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.not_txvAlbum, getActualSong().getAlbum());

        return not;
    }

    private void setListeners(RemoteViews view) {
        Intent previous = new Intent(NotificationBroadcast.NOTIFY_PREVIOUS);
        Intent next = new Intent(NotificationBroadcast.NOTIFY_NEXT);
        Intent playpause = new Intent(NotificationBroadcast.NOTIFY_PLAYPAUSE);
        Intent cancel = new Intent(NotificationBroadcast.NOTIFY_CANCEL);

        PendingIntent pPrevious = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, previous, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.not_btnPrevious, pPrevious);

        PendingIntent pPlayPause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, playpause, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.not_btnPlayPause, pPlayPause);

        PendingIntent pNext = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, next, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.not_btnNext, pNext);

        PendingIntent pCancel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, cancel, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.not_btnCancel, pCancel);
    }

    //endregion

    public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
        public MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

My Notification-Broadcastlistener:

```
public class NotificationBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String NOTIFY_PREVIOUS = "at.guger.musixs.musicservice.previous";
    public static final String NOTIFY_PLAYPAUSE = "at.guger.musixs.musicservice.playpause";
    public static final String NOTIFY_NEXT = "at.guger.musixs.musicservice.next";
    public static final String NOTIFY_CANCEL = "at.guger.musixs.musicservice.cancel";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MusicService musicService = (MusicService) context;

        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case NOTIFY_PLAYPAUSE:
                musicService.playPause();
                break;
            case NOTIFY_PREVIOUS:
                musicService.playPrev();
                break;
            case NOTIFY_NEXT:
                musicService.playNext();
                break;
            case NOTIFY_CANCEL:
                musicService.stop();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Since the App is closed as mentioned before, the notification is the only device to handle the MusicService!

**My main issue:**

This doesn't work:

```
...
System.out.println("Trying to stop"); //This is print out in the logcat
stopForeground(true);
System.out.println("stopped"); //This is not print out in the logcat
...
```

→ My conclusion: The service is getting stuck somewhere in the method `stopForeground`. The service is also not killed because it is restarted (seen in logcat). If my onBind returns `START_NOT_STICKY` instead of `START_STICKY`, the service isn't recreated but it isn't stopped at all!

Thanks!

Comment: Post the relevant code from your `Activity`. It isn't clear what your problem is.

Comment: I could post my two classes if this would help... My Problem: `stopForeground` isn't executed if my application is closed and the Service is playing Music!

Comment: You have a method `stop()`. I don't see who calls that method. Where is this method called?

Comment: i hope its clear now!

Comment: Let's assume that `stopForeground` works but the notification still cannot be swiped away. For this to work your device has to be at least API 21 and your app's targetSdkVersion must be at least 21. This is a known bug with Android and every app solves it by putting an "X" button inside the notification. If this is the case see [`NotificationCompat.MediaStyle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html) for help.

Comment: This will fail fast `MusicService musicService = (MusicService) context;` If this receiver is a nested class within `MusicService`, you can access it by `MusicService.this`.

Comment: In your `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` you do `MusicService musicService = (MusicService) context;`
This will always throw a `ClassCastException` because the context parameter is NOT a `Service`.

Comment: also post your manifest

Comment: And the stopForeground doesn't work because I don't get the line below print out!

Comment: And the onDestroy Event isn't called at all!

Comment: `onDestroy` is never called because the service never stops. `stopForeground` removes the foreground status, but the service lives on. Since you started the service with `Context.startService` it will live until you call `Context.stopService` or `Service.stopSelf()`. Also `bNotReceiverRegistered = false;` is missing from your `onDestroy`. Pro Tip: WATCH YOUR BLOODY EXCLAMATION POINTS!!! Pro Tip #2: Nobody is going to download and install your app from a third party website.

Comment: And why does stopSelf doesn't stop the Service? I've tried that before...

Comment: I also tried `stopForeground` and `stopService` afterwards. And after onDestroy the Service is "deleted", it doesn't matter if i set `bNotReceiver` to false or does it?

Answer (score 0):

the same problem with me and solved after change code order your code stop service of course but you start it again at last line in method onstartCommand so all you need is call   startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, notification); at first line in the enter code heremethod

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: start service ");

    startForeground(101,mBuilder.build());
    ....
    ....
    ...
    ....
}
```

what happens is in your switch case you Stop Service but Compile run code line by line so it  start Service again at last line  change order and it works fine